# C# DateTime Online without current device DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Here my point.
I have program that used data online and correct `DateTime` is importing for my work.
Normally I will use the client `DateTime`, but then the `DateTime` will not always be correct.

Why? Because User May change `DateTime` as he wish.. and other problems.

Let's Say I have this sample code

```
var TimeOnline = GetDateTimeOnline();
```

Now I get my server `DateTime` in var TimeOnline and it's working but not what I need, Do I have to used this functoin `GetDateTimeOnline()` ever time I need to check what is the `DateTime` in my server?

And sure I can't use this code

```
var date1 = DateTime.Now - TimeOnline;
```

To Know the difference `DateTime` between my server and client, to use this `DateTime.Now + date1` because user can change it any time.

Comment: I'm afraid it's really not clear what you're asking, to be honest. In particular, when you say it's "working but not what you need" what do you mean? It's possible that fetching the server time once and then using a `Stopwatch` would work, but it may have issues if the user "sleeps" their computer. (It's usually used for performance timing; I don't know what it does if the system sleeps.)

Comment: Daisy Shipton, I get My DateTime from my server but because Time is change ever second that my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once was in a situation quite similar to what you are describing.
I had a winforms application running on multiple computers, getting it's data from a WCF Service.

I had to show the server time to the user on the screen, as a running clock.

I ended up using a timer, but calculating the time passed from the server time, that I got from the WCF Server every time I connected to the service, and also, periodically sent a request specific to update the `datetime` (once every 5 minutes, if memory serves). I'm not sure what your situation exactly is, but it helped in mine so it might also help in yours.

Comment: the situation is the same to me, I have think this way too, is there any other way? like request DateTime from server only one.

Comment: I guess there are other ways to deal with it. In my case the service was in Europe and the clients in the far east, where the internet connection was slow and clunky, so I had no other choice but to calculate the time display locally. Perhaps you can find a better way to suit your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can request the current time on the server, and then compare the server time to the client time. You then calculate the seconds they differ, and store that value. (This might be a positive or a negative value.) Every time you want to calculate server time, take the client time, and add the seconds difference to client time, which should give you the current server time.

I suggest updating the seconds difference every five minutes or so.

Comment: You can see I talking about that in my Questing  (the difference DateTime between my server and client), Still I don't see any better way the problem if user change client DateTime before the updating.

Comment: If the user changing the date and time on their local machine is a real problem there is nothing you can do. The only option is to do everything that is important server side.